# Access value by index from nested dictionary of lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I am building a nested dictionary containing a list (so the nested key can hold multiple values):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from collections import defaultdict
import json

start = [1, 1, 19, 20, 30, 50, 50, 51]
events = ['event1', 'event1', 'event2', 'event2', 'event3', 'event4', 'event4', 'event4']
chroms = ['X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 1, 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z']

seen = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dict))

for c, b, e in zip(chroms, start, events):
    print c, b, e

    seen[c].setdefault(b, []).append(e)
```

This looks like:

```
print(json.dumps(seen, indent=4))

{
    "Y": {
        "19": [
            "event2"
        ], 
        "20": [
            "event2"
        ]
    }, 
    "X": {
        "1": [
            "event1", 
            "event1"
        ]
    }, 
    "Z": {
        "50": [
            "event4", 
            "event4"
        ], 
        "51": [
            "event4"
        ]
    }, 
    "1": {
        "30": [
            "event3"
        ]
    }
}
```

How can I access one of the list values by index?

I've tried: `print seen["X"]["1"][0]`, but I get:

> KeyError: 0

Comment: you can print the available keys with seen.keys() to get a better understanding of where the error is occurring :)

Comment: What do you get if you try `print seen["X"]["1"]`?

Answer (score 3):

Since you are printing the output of `json.dumps(seen, indent=4)` everything becomes a string (`json.dumps` returns a string, hence the `s` in `dumps`).

The actual key is `1`, not `"1"`:

```
print(seen["X"][1][0])
# event1
```

The reason you are getting `KeyError: 0` is due to the fact that you are using a `defaultdict` with `dict` factory. `seen["X"]["1"]` does not exist, hence a new empty dictionary is created:

```
print(seen["X"]["1"])
# {}
```

so of course `seen["X"]["1"][0]` will raise `KeyError: 0`.

Comment: Thanks. Voting to close because this was such a stupid mistake - a product of staring at the screen too long - and the title is probably going to prevent it from being broadly useful